# Crashlytics for Flutter does not report detailed on iOS, no Dart code, no line number

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, error-handling, crashlytics

My iOS users reported a crash, I tried to find it in Crashlytics (my dSym is already uploaded), but I see just this exception in the Crashlytics dashboard, it does not include source code filename and line number. And what is **optimized out**?:

```
flutter_error_exception type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' of '<optimized out>'

flutter_error_reason    thrown type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' of '<optimized out>'. Error thrown building Widget.
```

[image]